# How to avoid running surefire unit test with 'mvn site'

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

whenever I run 'mvn site' all my surefire unit tests gets executed. Is there any way to avoid running surefire unit tests while running mvn site. 
My pom is as mentioned below. I am using the below pom in parent project and all the modules are children of this pom.

```
<plugins>
    <!--For Unit tests -->
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
    </plugin>
    <!--For executing Integration tests in integration-test phase -->
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${failsafe.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <includes>
        <include>**/*IT.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
            <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
<!--For generating unit and integration test reports -->
<reporting>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
            <reports>
            <!--Disable all default reports -->
            </reports>
        </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire.version}</version>
        <configuration>
        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
        <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: You don't need to configure the [includes and excludes for maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes), cause these are the defaults of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

As per plugin [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/plugin-info.html), use `report-only`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
    <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
            <reports>
                <report>report-only</report>
            </reports>
        </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

[surefire-report:report-only](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-only-mojo.html): Creates a nicely formatted Surefire Test Report in html format. This goal does not run the tests, it only builds the reports. This is a workaround for https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-257

Answer (score 0):

Try with `mvn -DskipTests=true site`.

Comment: This works fine, but I wanted to know why does "mvn site" execute unit test only and not integration-test? Though I can force it to execute integration-test as well by binding integration-test goal to <site> phase in my pom, but then mvn site does not generate failsafe-report, seems like some problem in the way I am binding the goals to phases. Is there any way to exclude all tests without using any -D OR run both unit and Integ tests along with generating their report.

Comment: For that you need to understand the [Maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-core/lifecycles.html). `integration-test` is not a phase of the `site` lifecycle. And as for "I wanted to know why does "mvn site" execute unit test only and not integration-test?" - that's not what it says in the title and the description of this question.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity in the question. But this was my intention to ask this question so that I don't need to explicitly say -DskipTest everytime. I had already read http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html but that did not say anything about test goal binding with site lifecycle. Do you know about why is surefire test bound to mvn site lifecycle?

Comment: @MarcelStör Maven lifecycle tells that `surefire:test` is bound just to the `test` phase of the `default lifecyle`, it is not bound to any phase of either `clean` or site `lifecycle`